# Script for Desktop shortcut to "pin to startmenu" and unpin

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an application icon that is display on the Desktop (shortcut icon). If the user right click on the icons then there is an option to "Pin to Startmenu" and "Pin to TaskBar" after selecting the option then these icons shown on the Startmenu and taskbar and unpin to remove the from same loc.

But i need to perform these step via command prompt. Please suggest me how to execute via batch file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no programmatic access to these features - because every time windows *has* provided such features, every developer has decided that, of course, *their* program is so important it should go there.

Comment: The application icons store on the desktop so only single user can access the shortcut icons.